# Understanding the adjoint of an operator related to probability measures

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded, twice continuously differentiable function with bounded derivatives. Let $R_t$, $0 \leq t \leq T$, be a partial differential operator such that
$$
(R_t f)(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i(t,x) f'_{x_i}(x) + \sum_{ i, j = 1 }^n b_{i,j}(t,x) f''_{x_i x_j} (x), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^n,
$$
where the functions $a_i$ and $b_{i, j}$ are sufficiently nice. Let $\mu_t$, $0 \leq t \leq T$, be probability measures on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Consider the following notation:
$$
\langle f, \mu \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) \mu (dx).
$$
Hence
$$
\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (R_s f)(x) \mu_s (dx) ds= \int_{0}^t \langle R_s f, \mu_s \rangle.
$$
How can the following statement be understood:

> If $R_s^*$ is the adjoint of the operator $R_s$ then
> $$
> \int_0^t \langle R_s f, \mu_s \rangle = \langle f, \int_0^t R_s^* \mu_s ds \rangle?
> $$

Perhaps one can one justify such a relation,
$$
\langle R_s f, \mu_s \rangle = \langle f, R_s^* \mu_s \rangle,
$$
and further say that
$$
\int_0^t  \langle f, R_s^* \mu_s \rangle = \langle f, \int_0^t R_s^* ds \rangle?
$$
But then what is the adjoint in this context and why does it exist? What is the meaning of $R_s^*f$ and $\int_0^t R_s^* ds$? Are they both measures on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?